# Is it possible to make a script to automate that web scraping scenario?

Tags: javascript, java, python, automation, scripting

I need a script to automate the following web scraping process:

1. Use search filter on the webpage by entering a pre-given ID in a TextInput field.
2. Mark one of the listed results by clicking an icon next to it.
3. Press a button and wait for a data fetching process to complete
4. Extract HTML embedded text from the fetched data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Python I would recommend:

Selenium:  Selenium is a web testing library. It is used to automate browser activities.
BeautifulSoup: Beautiful Soup is a Python package for parsing HTML and XML documents. It creates parse-trees that are helpful in extracting data easily.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the Selenium library for Python or Java to accomplish this task.
All of your points should be possible with this library as far as I know.